# AES-256 ESSIV in dm-crypt

Tags: linux, aes, kernel, initialisation-vector, dm-crypt

I am playing around with disk encryption. https://gitlab.com/cryptsetup/cryptsetup/-/wikis/DMCrypt#iv-generators says:

> **essiv:** "encrypted sector|salt initial vector", the sector number is encrypted with the bulk cipher using a salt as key.
>   The salt is derived from the bulk cipher's key via hashing.
>   *Note that while the cipher algorithm is always as the same as the algorithm used for data encryption,   its key size depends on used hash algorithm.
>
>   In other words, while data encryption can use AES-128, the ESSIV calculation with SHA256 will use AES-256.
>
>   ESSIV takes hash algorithm as an option, so the format is essiv:hash, e.g. essiv:sha256.
>
>   Available since: 1.1.0 (kernel 2.6.10)*

The way I see it, I hash original KEY (32B), use this hash as key for **bulk cipher** (?) and encrypt sector number (8B) with it: result is used as IV for AES-256.

Now, do you have any idea which bulk cipher is it about? And what about its IV? I can't find anything about it in code: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v3.10/source/drivers/md/dm-crypt.c#L256. Thanks.

*EDIT: since ESSIV takes sector number 8B long it also has to be padded, possibly with zeros or PKCS7.*

Comment: Does [this](https://clemens.endorphin.org/nmihde/nmihde-A4-os.pdf) help?  

Quote:  
"*ESSIV derives the IV from key material via encryption of the sector numberwith a hashed version of the key material, the salt2. ESSIV does not specifya particular hash algorithmH, but the digest size of the hash must be a validkey size for the block cipher. For instance, sha256 is a valid choice for AES, assha256 produces a 256-bit digest.*"

Comment: Not what I am looking for but thanks, saved to bookmarks. Tomorrow I will try AES-256 with ECB as bulk cipher once again.

Comment: Ok, here: https://is.muni.cz/th/vesfr/final.pdf (page 30) I found that for ESSIV vector generation one should use the same exact block cipher as for finishing encryption. Now, since I am using CTR which turns block cipher into stream cipher, I presume I have to extend sector number to 16 bytes first to achieve 16 byte output. I will post answer when I find if it works. Good work, dr. Brož.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that in my case it was sufficient to use AES-256 ECB for ESSIV iv generation. I probably deceived myself by misinterpreting sentence:

> Note that while the cipher algorithm is always as the same as the
>   algorithm used for data encryption..

Although it makes sense, since IV usage in generation of primary IV is unnecesary in this case.